# converting Figma frame to webflow or wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web, figma, webflow

I am currently designing a website for my client, I was planning to develop the website using React but my client told me to do that in Wordpress or Webflow. I have completed the web designing in Figma, is there any way to convert my Figma frame ( That I have made in DESKTOP FRAME ) to WordPress or web flow through any plugins or magic?

Answer (score 0):

I have asked some WordPress developers and concluded that the Figma frame or file cannot be converted directly to WordPress or Webflow. Thanks!